# get data from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, netmiko

I have a list of dictionary which is built using tool I created using netmiko a python library. Currently I am  able to get the data in a list of dictionaries as below :

```
output_list = [{2: ['sjc01-0001-lsw01a', 'DCS-7280SR-48C6-R', '4.22.2.1F']}, {1: ['sjc01-0001-lsw01b', 'DCS-7280SR-48C6-R', '4.22.2.1F']}, {0: ['sjc01-0002-lsw02a', 'DCS-7280SR-48C6-R', '4.22.2.1F']}]
```

I am looking to sort the output_list with the key values which are 0,1,2 in this case and then print, so the output looks like the following :

```
{0: ['sjc01-0002-lsw02a', 'DCS-7280SR-48C6-R', '4.22.2.1F']}
{1: ['sjc01-0001-lsw01b', 'DCS-7280SR-48C6-R', '4.22.2.1F']}
{2: ['sjc01-0001-lsw01a', 'DCS-7280SR-48C6-R', '4.22.2.1F']}
```

Comment: Is it about python?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
d = {}
for i in range(len(output_list)):
    d.update(output_list[i])
k = list(d.keys())
k.sort()
for each in k:
    print('{{{0}: {1}}}'.format(each, d[each]))
```